# Objective-C Performance Optimization while using layer.shadow

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, optimization

I'm building news feed list table using `UITableView`. For each row I'm creating rectangle cell with shadow using **QuartzCore layer.shadow**
Sample code inside custom `UITableViewCell` class:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    bgView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
    bgView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;

    self.backgroundView = bgView;
    [bgView release];
}
```

When I test app, scroll `UITableView`, the scrolling performance is bad! If I remove shadow, performance is good!
**I need your advices**. What kind of optimizations I can do in order to get best performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't Objective-C but the shadow! Since iOS 3.2 you can define a `CGPathRef` for the shadow, you should build one which includes just the outline of your view to reduce rendering time and increase performance. You could also have the shadow rasterize to avoid redrawing it all the time (set the `shouldRasterize` property of your layer to `YES`. Depending on what you want to do with the layer, this might not be the best looking option. And its also a memory/performance trade off, keep that in mind!).

The most easiest way to create the needed shadow path should be via the `UIBezierPath` class which has a lot of useful class methods to build various formed `CGPathRef` objects, but depending on the shape of your view, you might have to fall back to build your own path by hand.

Comment: When I do shouldRasterize = YES; shadow quality becomes bad.

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek Like I said, that is just an option to turn on to further improve the performance. You don't have to enable it and in some cases it even makes the result worse (and clogs up memory).

Comment: If you enable shouldRasterize, you also have to set rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale, otherwise it will render at standard-def even on Retina devices (that's probably why it looked bad).

Answer (score 0):

how do you implement the `UITableView` delegate?
Have you created the `UITableViewCell` using reuse, such like:

```
-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]
```

Please check it.